# Using Programmable GUI in Matlab to display Multiple File Information in one Figure

Tags: matlab-figure, matlab-guide

```
function Display_Gui
    h = figure;
    TestInfo_Files=evalin('base','TestInfo_Files');
    for i=1:size(TestInfo_Files,1)
    Main_Panel = uipanel(h,'Title','Main-Panel','FontSize',10,...
         'BackgroundColor',[0.803 0.878 0.968],...
         'Position',[0 0.01*i 0.99 0.33]);
      %%Code for Text Display
    end
```

> I am using a format code to display static text for all files. The only difference would be data in those files.
>   [image about one structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASNbB.png)
>   As the number of files would change it should add on more sections with different data

Is it possible to have a scroll once I increase more files.

Comment: You could, but it seems like more effort than it's worth. MATLAB's [`'listbox' uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html#zmw57dd0e785704) and [`uitable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html) have this functionality built-in.

Comment: @excaza I am just using one main Figure File. So is it possible to have Scroll in that figure File as the number of Files selected increases.

Comment: It will be much easier if you just use a UI object designed for this.